# Curvature of space from approaching gravity sources affecting observations of expansion

Tags: gravity, spacetime, space-expansion

Since gravity curves space, I wonder how the locally increasing density of matter and energy due to the current galactic mergers with the Milky Way affects our perception of the universe.

Basically, if we have black holes coming closer to us, then the increasing curvature of space should make it look like the universe's expansion is accelerating, due to the increasing local gravitational red shift.

I'm sure I'm not the first to think of this but I wonder how well it's been studied, what the magnitude of that effect would be, and how we would even know if the curvature of space in our solar system were changing due to approaching gravitational fields.

Comment: Contracting or expanding space are just coordinate choices, so they don't influence physical observables.

Comment: I disagree @Sten. What he mentions doesn't really have anything exactly like this in research afaik, but e.g. local density anomalies like "voids" or similarly overdensities would affect our observations. And they have been taken into considerations and studied.

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 Framing the question in terms of contracting space makes it less clear what the actual physical question is. I do not claim there is no underlying physical question.

Comment: Contracting space is just the changing spacetime curvature near a large mass. "Contracting" because it's a red shift due to gravity.

Comment: Gravitational red shift is not just a coordinate choice. It's a real observable phenomenon.

Comment: Okay, I realized this was confusing my question. I rephrased it to what I believe is the correct standard terminology.

Comment: It's a little difficult to see what you mean, Eric. Are you referring to the approach of Andromeda (+ M33 and then the rest of the Local Group)? I mean, it's not like our view of the Observable Universe is obscured by a shell of Black Holes.

Comment: So right now, we're merging with the Sagittarius Dwarf Spheroidal Galaxy, the Canis Major Dwarf Galaxy and the Large and Small Magellanic Clouds, all of which, as I understand it, have some effect on us gravitationally. That means that the curvature in our local area of space is changing (our clocks run slower, and things far away look farther away). If that's true then we should see distant things moving ever so slightly farther away. Not that they are, but our measurements are distorted by the gravitational field we are in.

Comment: Locally, curvature isn't changing. You'd have to go very close to a Black Hole before your clock would run noticeably slower to mine.

Comment: Well, what's "very"? It's just a mass distance squared? And what's "noticable"? Atomic clocks already notice altitude. Granted it's because we're close. But I accept your main point which is that at the scales we're talking about, any effects on red shifts are undetectable.

Comment: You're on the right track if you're thinking about scale because the universe will have expanded between the time the light was emitted and us seeing it, causing the red-shifting. Regarding curvature again: if the Sun suddenly became a Black Hole, it wouldn't affect Earth's orbit and your clock would run the same. You wouldn't notice until it got dark and cold after eight minutes. So, like I said, you'd have to go to the Black Hole to start making measurements.

Comment: The black hole reference was just a way to talk about a strong local gravitational field. Did you see this?physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170525/… it makes it seem like very subtle changes are still detectable, though still possibly negligible as you propose.

Comment: @EricHeitzman Yes, I think I know what you mean: the supermassive bodies in galactic centres are significant, but if space wasn't so vast there'd be a whole lot more chaos than a bit of red-shift coming along with the mergers. At least in the case of Andromeda, there are predicted to be few actual collisions. I agree with the answers posted here so I won't waffle on. Also, if you want another user to see your directed comments, you'll need to put their name after an @, just the way I've done at the beginning of this comment to you. Otherwise, they won't be notified. Best of luck.

Comment: @Wookie Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A back of the envelope calculation shows that the gravitational effect of the Andromeda galaxy in the vicinity of Earth is somewhat less than the gravitational effect of Alpha Centauri, which is to say, negligible. For all practical purposes the spacetime curvature here due to distant galaxies is 0.

Comment: That sounds reasonable I suppose. I'm not sure how subtle the expansion discrepancy would be. And the second part of the question? If our local curvature were changing, how would we know?

Comment: If our local curvature were changing then the orbits of planets (which are following geodesics in curved spacetime) would change.

Comment: Possibly, but not very much if it all changed at the same time. The gradient would be pretty constant between the distant orbits and the sun.

Answer (score 2):

Gravitational redshift is proportional to the change of gravitational potential between where the light was emitted and where it is received.

If you were positioned in a region where the local density of mass was increasing, then this would result in a numerically *decreasing* gravitational redshift.

These shifts apply to all light we receive from beyond our galaxy and local group, are *tiny* compared with cosmological redshifts and would not produce any significant relationship between redshift and distance.

e.g., The Solar System sits in a galaxy with $M\sim 10^{11} M_\odot$ within a radius of about 8 kpc. The gravitational redshift at that position is approximately
$$z \sim -\frac{GM}{Rc^2} = -6\times 10^{-6}\ ,$$
equivalent to *subtracting* a recession velocity of just 1.8 km/s for light entering the galaxy from outside. Adding more mass within the solar circle would increase this blue shift.

Comment: So you're saying if my clock runs slower than a system emitting some light, the the light I receive is blue shifted relative to the source? Are you very sure about that?

Comment: Anyway, what we're actually interested in is the change in the curvature, taking into account the motion of the galaxies. The idea is that it might result in a small perceived acceleration of the expansion of the universe. I appreciate your calculations. Maybe there's not enough information to answer the questions if we can't measure the changes in our local curvature.

Comment: @EricHeitzman that's right. And light emitted by you, in the gravitational potential, is observed redshifted  by a distant observer. Gravitational redshift is not directly related to the curvature of space or the gravitational field, it is approximately proportional to the change in gravitational potential https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: that's helpful. Thank you. I'll never trust ChatGPT again. :-) I get that the shift is determined by a potential, but still, how would you measure a changing potential between your frame and other distant light source? Could you expect to do it by measuring a drift in the (blue) shift? Or is it essentially unmeasurable? Gravity wave detectors measure it on a small time scale I guess.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about redshift drift. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170525/how-does-a-particular-galaxys-apparent-recessional-velocity-change-as-the-unive @EricHeitzman

Comment: Wow. That's fascinating. It's evidence that the drift can be measured. They were able to detect a 0.1 m/s change over 20 years. That's certainly in the ballpark you calculated. I'm still curious if you could tell whether those measured drifts were from our changes. Maybe you'd just rely on calculations from the motions of know gravity sources.

Comment: Okay, so the conclusion I'm coming to is: (1.) It's actually a blue shift (thanks @ProfRob), and (2.) it's not clear if it has been studied, because (3.) The effect is assumed to be exceedingly small based on our knowledge of the movement of local masses that would influence our curvature, and I guess (4.)  there is no possible way to measure changes in our local curvature.